# WP site in infinite redirect loop

Tags: redirect

**UPDATE**: In Cloudflare - Despite being in DEV mode, I turned OFF redirect to HTTPS: and this got past the infinite loop. However, if you use the 301 Redirect checker, you can see it is going from https://www.pokerdiy.com to http://www.pokerdiy.com to https://pokerdiy.com which is very odd - how to prevent the 301 to http?

I think this is a new issue - I have not made any obvious changes lately:

The canonical URL I want is https://pokerdiy.com

- If I go to http://pokerdiy.com it redirects to https://pokerdiy.com correctly
- If I go to https://pokerdiy.com it works correctly
- If I go to http://www.pokerdiy.com it gets into an infinite loop
- If I go to  https://www.pokerdiy.com it gets into an infinite loop

According to http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php and enter https://www.pokerdiy.com it seems to alternate between http and https until it eventually timesout.

**Possible suspects:**

- WP Redirection module (currently disabled)
- Cloudflare (Switched to Dev Mode)
- WP Rocket (currently disabled)
- RankMath (currently disabled)
- Kinsta Host - turned off Redirect setting to HTTPs

Any suggestions appreciated please.

```
>>> https://www.pokerdiy.com

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Thu, 26 Mar 2020 00:19:51 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d86e44ea081ac34eddfeca3495d0879e21585181991; expires=Sat, 25-Apr-20 00:19:51 GMT; path=/; domain=.pokerdiy.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Location:   http://www.pokerdiy.com/
CF-Ray: 579cb3d68917e5f8-LHR
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains; preload
CF-Cache-Status:    DYNAMIC
Expect-CT:  max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
RJCF:   MISS
x-cfw-cache:    MISS
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
alt-svc:    h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400




>>> http://www.pokerdiy.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Thu, 26 Mar 2020 00:19:51 GMT
Connection: close
Cache-Control:  max-age=3600
Expires:    Thu, 26 Mar 2020 01:19:51 GMT
Location:   https://www.pokerdiy.com/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 579cb3d7b863e630-LHR
alt-svc:    h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400
```

Comment: Turn off all the plugins turn them on one by one

Comment: Thanks, I have done this. No joy. I don't think it is at plugin level

Comment: What is the site URL in wp_options https://domain.com or https://www.domain.com?

Comment: https://pokerdiy.com  (with https:// and no wwww)

Comment: Where does the a record of domain redirect to, https://www or https:// without www?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ffL2YTk.png  (A points to IP, Cname is without www (Unable to put the protocol in Cloudflare))

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all those who tried to help. I was able to rule out many options by disabling all plugins, cloudflare etc. but the problem persisted.

The root cause turned out to be my own configuration on my host (Kinsta) when adding the SSL cert from LetsEncrypt.

I had bound the certificate to https://pokerdiy.com and not also to http://www.pokerdiy.com.

As soon as I bound it to both then the redirect error disappears.

Thanks to Kinsta's great tech support for helping me find the root cause,  I don't think I would have spotted it otherwise...